# TDD, How to write tests that will compile even if objects don't exist

Tags: tdd, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS 2012, but that's not really important.

What is important is that I'm trying to do some TDD by writing all my tests first and then creating the code.

However, the app will not compile because none of my objects or methods exist.

Now, to my mind, I should be able to create ALL my tests but still run my app so I can debug etc.  The tests shouldn't prevent compilation because objects and methods are missing.

I thought the whole point of it was that as you develop your tests you can begin to see duplications etc so that you can refactor before writing a single line of code.

So the question is, is there a way to do this or am I doing this wrong?

**EDIT**
I am using VS2012 and C#

Answer (score 6):

I see a small problem with

> writing all my tests first and then creating the code.

You don't need to write **ALL** your tests first, you just need one, make it fail, make it pass and repeat. That means ideally at any point you should have ideally **one** failing test.

A compile failure counts as a failed test in that sense. So the next step is to make it pass - i.e. add stubs or return default values to make it compile. The test would then be red.. then work at getting it to green.

Answer (score 5):

Test Driven Development is about very small iterations.  You don't define all your tests up front.  You create one test based on one fraction of one requirement.  Then you implement the code to pass that test.  Once it's passing, you work on another fraction of a requirement.

The idea is that trying to do all the design up front (whether it be creating detailed class diagrams or creating a bunch of tests) means that you will find it too expensive to change a weakness in your design, so you won't improve your code.

Here's an example.  Let's say you decide to use inheritance to relate two objects, but when you started implementing the objects, you found that made testing them tough.  You discover it would be much easier to test each object individually, and relate them via containment instead.  What is happening is the tests are driving your design in a more loosely coupled direction.  This is a very good outcome of TDD - you are using tests to improve the design.

If you had written all your tests in advance assuming your design decision of inheritance was a good choice, you would either throw away a lot of work, or you would say "it's too tough to make a change like that now, so I'll just live with this sub-optimal design instead."

You can certainly create business-rule-related acceptance tests in advance.  Those are called behavior tests (part of Behavior Driven Development, or BDD) and they are good to test features of the software from the user's point of view.  But those are NOT unit tests.  Unit tests are for testing code from the developer's point of view.  Creating the unit tests in advance defeats the purpose of TDD, because it will make testing harder, it will prevent you from improving your code, and will often lead to rebellion and failure of the practice.  That's why it's important to do it right.

Answer (score 4):

> What is important is that I'm trying to do some TDD by writing all my tests first and then creating the code.

The problem is that "writing all my tests first" is most emphatically **not** "do[ing] some TDD". Test driven development consists of lots of small repetitions of the "red-green-refactor" cycle:

- Add a unit test to the test suite, run it and watch it fail (red)
- Add just enough code to the system under test to make all the tests
  pass (green)
- Improve the design of the system under test (typically
  by removing duplication) while keeping all the tests passing
  (refactor)

If you code an entire huge test suite up front, you'll spend forever trying to get to the "green" (all tests passing) state.

> However, the app will not compile because none of my objects or methods exist.

That's typical of any compiled language; it's not a TDD issue per se. All it means is that, in order to watch the new test fail, you may have to write a minimal stub for whatever feature you're currently working on to make the compiler happy.

For example, I might write this test (using NUnit):

```
[Test]
public void DefaultGreetingIsHelloWorld()
{
    WorldGreeter target = new WorldGreeter();
    string expected = "Hello, world!";
    string actual = target.Greet();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

And I'd have to then write this much code to get the app to compile and the test to fail:

```
public class WorldGreeter
{
    public string Greet()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Once I've gotten the solution to build and I've seen the one failing test, I can add the code to make the first test pass:

```
    public string Greet()
    {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
```

Once all tests pass, I can look through the system under test and see what could be done to improve the design. However, it's essential to the TDD discipline to go through both the "red" and "green" steps before playing around with refactoring.

> I thought the whole point of it was that as you develop your tests you can begin to see duplications etc so that you can refactor before writing a single line of code.

Martin Fowler defines [refactoring](http://refactoring.com) as "a disciplined technique for restructuring an existing body of code, **altering its internal structure without changing its external behavior**" (emphasis added). If you haven't written a single line of code, there's nothing to refactor.

> So the question is, is there a way to do this or am I doing this wrong?

If you're looking to do TDD, then, yes, I fear you are doing this wrong. You may well be able to deliver great code doing what you're doing, but it isn't TDD; whether or not that's a problem is for you to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**No. It's about coding just enough to verify the implementation of the required use cases**

You can define your tests cases early,  but to code the test cases them you iteratively write a test, have it fail. Then write some code that ensures that the code passes.

Then rinse and repeat until all  your test cases are covered,

Edit to address comment.

As you build out the code, that's where your *programming* designs and faults are identified. Extreme programming lends it self to you being able to change code with out care as the test base protects your requirements. Your intentions are good but the reality is that you'll refactor/redesign test test cases as you discover design issues and flaws through building out the code and test base.

However IMHO, in a very general case, a test that doesn't compile is effectively a meta test that's failing that needs to be corrected before moving on. It's telling you to write some code!

Comment: Yeah I get that but by doing it that way I will have written bad code. Writing all the tests first would identify problem areas, duplicates and bad design me thinks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create your empty class with stub functions, no?

```
class Whatever {
    char *foo( const char *name ) {}

    int can_wibble( Bongo *myBongo ) {}
}
```

Then you can compile.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i'm using C#.  My mistake

Comment: Like you said, the language doesn't matter.  Make your function definitions and make them not do anything.  Then you can compile against them.

Comment: Yeah so have the stubs there and refactor them as needed during test design +1

Answer (score 0):

Use mock, from Wikipiedia: mock objects are simulated objects that mimic the behavior of real objects in controlled ways. A programmer typically creates a mock object to test the behavior of some other object, in much the same way that a car designer uses a crash test dummy to simulate the dynamic behavior of a human in vehicle impacts.

Please refer [this](http://alexott.net/en/cpp/CppTestingIntro.html).

Comment: ah right, yeah that might just work.  pity i need to mock everything then tho

Comment: if Mock is used in the right way, it help you to get a good design.

Answer (score 0):

I found this using dynamic for objects that don't exists yet:
https://coderwall.com/p/0uzmdw

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference